# Magnific pop-up only links to you tube

Tags: magnific-popup

I've taken the code from the example to try to make it work, but my link only links out to youtube.

I linked out to the scripts and styles to try to get it to work, but that didn't help. I'm completely new to this so your help is much appreciated.

```
<div class="example gc3">

<div class="html-code">
  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O2aH4XLbto" class="popup-youtube">Open YouTube video</a><br>
 </div>
```

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
      disableOn: 700,
      type: 'iframe',
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
      removalDelay: 160,
      preloader: false,

      fixedContentPos: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: No when I click on the link that should trigger the popup it just opens up the video on the youtube site.